# How to embeded shortcode for another website

Tags: shortcode

I have few website and want to embedded shortcode to another website.

Means, 1st website has contact form with shortcode example [form id="123"]

Now I want to insert this shortcode in all other website.

So avoid unnecessary plugin installation in all website and easily check in only one website.

How can this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No way; shortcode is related to the plugin installed on the website you can't reuse it.